# Number Theory: Show for all positive integers σ(2n)>2σ(n)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Just need a bit of help with this.

Number Theory: Show for all positive integers σ(2n)>2σ(n)

Sigma being the function of total numbers of factors including 1 and itself from number theory

I know a good starting point would be to consider n=2^r m, but I'm really stuck on how to apply this to achieve the proof.

Thank you.

Comment: What is $\sigma$?

Comment: Sorru could ypu specify what you mean by that sigma?

Comment: Probably the divisor function.

Comment: $\sigma$ is probably either the sum of divisors or number of divisors. The result is true for sum, I haven't looked into number. But it would be nice to definitively know which one.

Comment: The number can't be true since $\sigma(2) = 2$ and $\sigma(4) = 3$

Comment: Sorry guys sigma is the function of total numbers of factors including 1 and itself from number theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution (again assuming $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of the divisors of $n$):

$\sigma$ is multiplicative. Let $n=2^io$ where $o$ is odd. Then
$$\sigma(2n)=\sigma(2^{i+1})\sigma(o) = (2^{i+2}-1)\sigma(o),$$ but
$$2\sigma(n)=2\sigma(2^i)\sigma(o)=2(2^{i+1}-1)\sigma(o)=(2^{i+2}-2)\sigma(o).$$

Then we see that $\sigma(2n)=2\sigma(n)+\sigma(o)$, or that $\sigma(2n) > 2\sigma(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

$ \sigma(n)$  is the sum of the divisors of $n$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sigma(n)= \sum_{ d \mid n} d.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now if $d \mid n $ then $ 2d \mid 2n$ (and there could be other values that divide $2n$) so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sigma(2n) \geq  \sum_{ 2d \mid 2n} 2d = 2\sum_{ d \mid n} d = 2 \sigma(n).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: +1 Let me just add that you need the equivalence $d|n \iff 2d|2n$, the implication is not sufficient. Also there are other values that divide 2n (1 for instance), thus we have a strict inequality

Comment: Although technically this doesn't give the strict inequality, you can note that $1$ is not counted in the first sum, and add that in to get the strict version. (+1)